# Reading from google storage gs:// filesystem from local spark instance

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

The problem is quite simple: You have a local spark instance (either cluster or just running it in local mode) and you want to read from gs://

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am submitting here the solution I have come up with by combining different resources:

1. Download the google  cloud storage connector : [gs-connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/google-cloud-storage-connector) and store it in `$SPARK/jars/` folder (Check *Alternative 1* at the bottom)
2. Download the `core-site.xml` file from [here](https://github.com/spotify/gcs-tools/blob/master/shared/src/main/resources/core-site.xml), or copy it from below. This is a configuration file used by hadoop, (which is used by spark).
3. Store the `core-site.xml` file in a folder. Personally I create the `$SPARK/conf/hadoop/conf/` folder and store it there.
4. In the spark-env.sh file indicate the hadoop conf fodler by adding  the following line: `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
   =</absolute/path/to/hadoop/conf/>`
5. Create an OAUTH2 key from the respective page of Google (`Google Console-> API-Manager-> Credentials`).
6. Copy the credentials to the `core-site.xml` file.

Alternative 1: Instead of copying the file to the `$SPARK/jars` folder, you can store the jar in any folder and add the folder in the spark classpath. One way is to edit `SPARK_CLASSPATH`  in the ``` spark-env.sh``folder but ```SPARK_CLASSPATH` is now deprecated. Therefore one can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit) on how to add a jar in the spark classpath

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.gs.impl</name>
        <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem</value>
        <description>Register GCS Hadoop filesystem</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable</name>
        <value>false</value>
        <description>Force OAuth2 flow</description>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>fs.gs.auth.client.id</name>
        <value>32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com</value>
        <description>Client id of Google-managed project associated with the Cloud SDK</description>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>fs.gs.auth.client.secret</name>
        <value>fslkfjlsdfj098ejkjhsdf</value>
        <description>Client secret of Google-managed project associated with the Cloud SDK</description>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>fs.gs.project.id</name>
        <value>_THIS_VALUE_DOES_NOT_MATTER_</value>
        <description>This value is required by GCS connector, but not used in the tools provided here.
  The value provided is actually an invalid project id (starts with `_`).
      </description>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I followed all the steps but got the following error in pyspark:

    `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
    z:org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get.
    : java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs`

I am worried that pyspark does not run spark-env.cmd (I am using Windows). It would help to check that core-site.xml gets picked up but I don't know how...

Comment: Probably the spark-instance cannot find the driver.

Answer (score 8):

In my case on Spark 2.4.3 I needed to do the following to enable GCS access from Spark local. I used a JSON keyfile vs. the `client.id/secret` proposed above.

1. In `$SPARK_HOME/jars/`, use the shaded `gcs-connector` jar from here: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/bigdataoss/gcs-connector/hadoop2-1.9.17/ or else I had various failures with transitive dependencies.
2. (Optional) To my `build.sbt` add:

   ```
   "com.google.cloud.bigdataoss" % "gcs-connector" % "hadoop2-1.9.17"
       exclude("javax.jms", "jms")
       exclude("com.sun.jdmk", "jmxtools")
       exclude("com.sun.jmx", "jmxri")
   ```
3. In `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`, add:

   ```
   spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable       true
   spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile /path/to/my/keyfile
   ```

And everything is working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. is it possible to add an example of the JSON keyfile?

Comment: the key file should be just the usual service account keys, described here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys

Answer (score 3):

Considering that it has been awhile since the last answer, I though I would share my recent solution. Note, the following instruction is for Spark 2.4.4.

1. Download the "gcs-connector" for the type of Spark/Hadoop you have got from [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage). Search for "Other Spark/Hadoop clusters" topic.
2. Move the "gcs-connector" to $SPARK_HOME/jars. See more about $SPARK_HOME below.
3. Make sure that all the environment variables are properly set up for you Spark application to run. This is:
   a. SPARK_HOME pointing to the location where you have saved Spark installations.
   b. GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to the location where json key is. If you have just downloaded it, it will be in your ~/Downloads
   c. JAVA_HOME pointing to the location where you have your Java 8* "Home" folder.

   If you are on Linux/Mac OS you can use `export VAR=DIR`, where VAR is variable and DIR the location, or if you want to set them up permanently, you can add them to ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc files.
   For Windows OS users, in cmd write `set VAR=DIR` for shell related operations, or `setx VAR DIR` to store the variables permanently.

That has worked for me and I hope it help others too.

* Spark works on Java 8, therefore some of its features might not be compatible with the latest Java Development Kit.

Answer (score 2):

Try following configuration using PySpark. JARS_PATH is a string variable, containing absolute path to jar files. Do set up required environment variables.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    
JARS_PATH = '/LOCATION-TO-JARS/gcs-connector-hadoop3-latest.jar,/LOCATION-TO-JARS/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar'

spark = sparkSession.builder.appName(SPARK_APP_NAME).config('spark.jars’,JARS_PATH).getOrCreate()
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.impl', 'com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem')
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable', 'ture')
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.project.id', ‘MY-GCP-PROJECT-ID’)
    spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
```