# Spark java with Google Store

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage

Can some please share any examples on spark java read and write files from Google Store.

Thanks You in advance.

Comment: Probably you can go through this steps to read files from gsf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716055/reading-from-google-storage-gs-filesystem-from-local-spark-instance

Answer (score 1):

Good Store is should be backed by Google cloud there have a lot of Apache Spark and Hadoop APIs for Java examples it maybe useful for you

```
https://cloud.google.com/java/samples
https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/
```

Also here have a lot of Java for Spark jobs read/write files from Google Store

```
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-examples/tree/master/gaming/java/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/sparkdemo
```