# How to read csv file from GCS using spark-java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to read csv file which is stored in GCS using spark,
I have a simple spark java project which does nothing but reading a csv.
the following code are used in it.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Hello world");
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read().option("header", true).option("sep", "" + ",").option("delimiter", "\"").csv("gs://abc/WDC_age.csv");
```

but it throws an error which says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs
```

can anyone help me in this?
I just want to read csv from GCS using spark.

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading from google storage gs:// filesystem from local spark instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716055/reading-from-google-storage-gs-filesystem-from-local-spark-instance)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i just added the following dependency on my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
        <version>hadoop3-2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

and it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

`No FileSystem for scheme: gs` indicates Spark couldn't find the GCS connector. I guess you are not running in a Dataproc cluster, you might need to install the connector by yourself
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage