# SparkContext.addJar does not work in local mode

Tags: apache-spark

When there is a jar file needed in a spark job, it needs to be added into spark job through 2 ways:
1. `--jar path` option in command.
2. `SparkContext.addJar("path")`.
Can anyone tell me the difference between the these 2 ways?
From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit/37348234#comment73010392_37348234), the answer is they are identical and only priority is different, but I don't think it is true. If I submit the spark job in yarn cluster mode, the addJar() will not work if jar files are not included in option `--jars` in command according to [official site](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/running-on-yarn.html).

> The --jars option allows the SparkContext.addJar function to work if
>   you are using it with local files and running in yarn-cluster mode. It
>   does not need to be used if you are using it with HDFS, HTTP, HTTPS,
>   or FTP files.

The reason is that the driver runs on different machine than the client. So it seems that option `--jars` in command is from client and function `addJar()` can only work on jars in the driver.

Then I did a test in local mode.

1.`spark-shell --master local --jars path/to/jar`

If I start spark-shell in this way, object in the jar can be used in the spark-shell

2.`spark-shell --master local`

If I start spark-shell in this way and use `sc.addJar("path/to/jar")`, objects within the jar file cannot be imported into the spark-shell and I got `class cannot be found` error.

My questions are:

Why the method `SparkContext.addJar()` does not work in local mode?

What is the difference between `SparkContext.addJar()` and `--jars`?

My environment: hortonworks 2.5 cluster and version of spark is 1.6.2. I appreciate if anyone can shed some light on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after some research, I found the reason. Just post here if there is someone else involved into this problem.

Method `addJar()` does not add jars into driver's classpath. What the method does is to find jars in driver node, distribute into worker nodes and then add into executors' classpath.
Because I submit my spark job in local mode, driver classpath (I guess) is used in the spark job, the jars added by method `addJar()` cannot be found.

In order to solve this problem, use `--jars` option to include all jars when submit the spark job or use `--driver-class-path` to add jars.
More details can be found [here](https://github.com/QingyangKong/knowledge-dump/blob/master/spark/classpath_conf.md).