# How to add Jars while spark-shell is running?

Tags: apache-spark

I need to add multiple jars to my spark-shell. So, I added them using --jars. Suddenly, after some time, I realize I need to add one more and I'm in between a job on which I already spent 2 hrs. So, is there any way to add jar at this point of time. I hope there should be something or else this issue can cause a big trouble.

Comment: What is your usecase ,why you need to add many jars ?

Comment: sc.addJar("/path/to/your/jar") https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964131/sparkcontext-addjar-does-not-work-in-local-mode

Comment: gasprams' answer should work. You could also save your intermediate result and restart your shell.

Comment: yes it's working!