# Adding a jar file to pyspark after context is created

Tags: python, apache-spark, jar

I am using pyspark from a notebook and I do not handle the creation of the SparkSession.
I need to load a jar containing some functions I would like to use while processing my rdds. This is something which you can easily do using --jars which I cannot do in my particular case. 
Is there a way to access the spark scala context and call the addJar method? I tried to use the JavaGateway (sparksession._jvm...) but have not been successful so far. Any idea?

Thanks
Guillaume

Answer (score 3):

sparksession._jsc.addJar does the job.

Comment: ... but it solves my problem only partially as the method is node available on my driver node!

Comment: I found this very useful [post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this method, which will add the file to the context of all nodes:

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile("filename")
```

Answer (score 1):

distribute xxx.jar by addJar and import it by extraClassPath

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'xxx.jar').getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext._jsc.addJar('/xxx/xxx/xxx.jar')
```