# Apache Spark : Adding third party jars programmatically

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have tried following ways to add jars in my code:

1)

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp")
                 .setMaster(local[*])
                 .setJars(new String[]{"jar1.jar","jar2.jar"});
```

2)

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp")
                 .setMaster(local[*])
                 .set("spark.jars","path/to/jars");
```

3)

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp")
                 .setMaster(local[*]);
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf)
                      .addJar("path/to/jars")`
```

But still getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for third party library
classes.

Whereas same code is running fine when I run it with --jars option like
`./spark-submit --class com.test.spark.App --jars jar1.jar,jar2.jar main.jar`

Spark version : spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7

Comment: How are you generating the jar? Do you create an uber-jar?

Comment: yes I am creating uber-jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit Pls look for "SparkContext.addJar vs SparkContext.addFile" in accepted answer.

Comment: @hadooper  gone through the link, tried addFile also no luck.