# How to define log path configuration to spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to pass a log path to `spark-submit` as follows:

```
spark-submit \
  --master local[*] \
  --conf -Dlogback.configurationFile=C:\Users\A661758\Desktop\logback.xml \
  target\scala-2.11\dataintegrationRepriseExistant-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  C:\Users\A661758\Desktop\Atos_Integration_Donnees_V0.1_2017\AC_LIMOGES_JSON SourceAcLimoges 20170526 L AC-LIMOGES
```

Output :

> Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property:
>   -Dlogback.configurationFile=C:\User
>       s\A661758\Desktop\logback.xml
>       log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (dataIntegrationENTLea.Main$).

Answer (score 2):

Spark is rightly telling you that any argument passed to `--conf` needs to be a spark configuration key. What you're looking for is `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` and `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`:

```
spark-submit \
--master local[*] \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlogback.configurationFile=C:\Users\A661758\Desktop\logback.xml" \ 
C:\Users\A661758\dataIntegrationLea\target\scala-2.11\dataintegrationRepriseExistant-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jarC:\Users\A661758\Desktop\Atos_Integration_Donnees_V0.1_2017\AC_LIMOGES_JSON SourceAcLimoges 20170526 L AC-LIMOGES
```

Note you need to set both the driver and the executor location accordingly, as they may be different on each machine.

For more on spark configuration values, see [Add jars to a Spark Job - spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit/37348234#37348234)

Comment: @Mounir What isn't working? What are the error messages? Add them to your question.

Comment: The specified path was not found    :     spark-submit --class dataIntegrationENTLea.Main --master local[*] --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlogback.configurationFile=C:\Users\A661758\Desktop\test\logback.xml"  local:/C:/Users/A661758/dataIntegrationLea/target/scala-2.11/dataIntegrationENTLea-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar C:/Users/A661758/Desktop/Atos_Integration_Donnees_V0.1_2017/AC_LIMOGES_JSON SourceAcLimoges 20170526 L AC-LIMOGES

Comment: Are you running this locally in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, in my IDE it's woking

Answer (score 2):

It won't work for `local[*]` as it's too late to set up the single JVM for the driver and the single executor (that's again the driver).

```
--master local[*] --conf -Dlogback.configurationFile=C:\Users\A661758\Desktop\logback.xml
```

Not to mention that setting such parameters is through `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` or `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` as described in [Runtime Environment](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment):

> **spark.driver.extraJavaOptions** A string of extra JVM options to pass to the driver. For instance, GC settings or other logging.
>
> **spark.executor.extraJavaOptions** A string of extra JVM options to pass to executors. For instance, GC settings or other logging.

When you read the documentation, you should find the following (highlighting mine):

> Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the `SparkConf` directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. **Instead, please set this through the `--driver-java-options` command line option or in your default properties file**.

When you execute `spark-submit --help` you should see the following:

> **--driver-java-options** Extra Java options to pass to the driver.

Use `--driver-java-options` as follows:

```
./bin/spark-shell --driver-java-options -Daaa=bbb
```

and check out web UI's **Environment** tab if the option is set.

[image]