# Spark.jars not adding jars to classpath

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to add my custom jar in spark job using "spark.jars" property.
Although I can read the info in logs of jar getting added but when I check the jars that are added to the classpath, I don't find it.Below are the functions that I also have tried it out.

1)spark.jars

2)spark.driver.extraLibraryPath

3)spark.executor.extraLibraryPath

4)setJars(Seq[String])

But none added the jar.I am using spark 2.2.0 in HDP and files were kept locally.
Please let me know what possibly I am doing wrong.

First option worked for me.Spark.jars was adding jar as it was being shown in Spark UI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add jars to a Spark Job - spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit)

Answer (score 1):

If you need an external jar available to the executors, you can try `spark.executor.extraClassPath`. According to the documentation it shouldn't be necessary, but it helped me in the past

> Extra classpath entries to prepend to the classpath of executors. This exists primarily for backwards-compatibility with older versions of Spark. Users typically should not need to set this option.

Documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Tried that earlier and had also mentioned in my question that what i have tried all.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation for submitting jobs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management), adding extra non-runtime jars is at the bottom

You can either add the jars to the `spark.jars` in the [SparkConf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) or specify them at runtime

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
```

so try
`spark-submit --master yarn --jars the_jar_i_need.jar my_script.py`

For example, I have a pyspark script `kafak_consumer.py` that requires a jar, `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.1.1.jar`

To run it the command is

```
spark-submit --master yarn --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.1.1.jar kafka_consumer.py
```

Comment: I am asking for external jars, not application jar.

Comment: Tried this but no result.