# Spark-Submit: --packages vs --jars

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cassandra

Can someone explain the differences between `--packages` and `--jars` in a spark-submit script?

```
nohup ./bin/spark-submit   --jars ./xxx/extrajars/stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar,./xxx/extrajars/stanford-parser-3.8.0.jar \
--packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.7 \
--class xxx.mlserver.Application \
--conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=192.168.0.33 \
--conf spark.cores.max=4 \
--master spark://192.168.0.141:7077  ./xxx/xxxanalysis-mlserver-0.1.0.jar   1000  > ./logs/nohup.out &
```

Also, do I require the`--packages` configuration if the dependency is in my applications `pom.xml`? (I ask because I just blew up my applicationon by changing the version in `--packages` while forgetting to change it in the `pom.xml`)

I am using the `--jars` currently because the jars are massive (over 100GB) and thus slow down the shaded jar compilation. I admit I am not sure why I am using `--packages` other than because I am following datastax documentation

Answer (score 49, accepted):

if you do `spark-submit --help` it will show:

```
--jars JARS                 Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver
                              and executor classpaths.

--packages                  Comma-separated list of maven coordinates of jars to include
                              on the driver and executor classpaths. Will search the local
                              maven repo, then maven central and any additional remote
                              repositories given by --repositories. The format for the
                              coordinates should be groupId:artifactId:version.
```

if it is **--jars**

> then spark doesn't hit maven but it will search specified jar in the local file system  it also supports following URL scheme hdfs/http/https/ftp.

so if it is **--packages**

> then spark will search specific package in local maven repo then central maven repo or any repo provided by --repositories and then download it.

Now Coming back to your questions:

*Also, do I require the--packages configuration if the dependency is in my applications pom.xml?*

**Ans**: No, If you are not importing/using classes in jar directly but need to load classes by some class loader or service loader (e.g. JDBC Drivers). Yes otherwise.

BTW, If you are using specific version of specific jar in your pom.xml then why dont you make uber/fat jar of your application or provide dependency jar in **--jars** argument ? instead of using **--packages**

links to refer:

[spark advanced-dependency-management](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management)

[add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37348234/3182598)

Comment: Thanks, I have an uber jar, I am trying to figure out what goes in the jar and what can be called via packages. Your response is helpful