# Error while running via spark-submit while connecting to google BQ

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

Written a spark code which Google BQ using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector Made the changes as mentioned in the library spec. When I run the job from the IDE (Intellij), it's running fine and connecting to Bq. Whereas when I tried to run via spark-submit, it's giving below error. Any clue where I am going wrong?

```
spark-submit --class xxx.Boot --master local[1] /user/xx/app/target/app.jar
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.package$BigQueryDataFrameReader.bigquery(package.scala:24)
    at spark.Boot$.delayedEndpoint$spark$Boot$1(Boot.scala:56)
    at spark.Boot$delayedInit$body.apply(Boot.scala:17)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at spark.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at opp.spark.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bigquery.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:634)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, that you should either specify the dependencies of your project (including bigquery) in the command line with the jar or the packages option, or make an uberjar including those dependencies. See here: [Spark-Submit: --packages vs --jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434808/spark-submit-packages-vs-jars) and here: [Is it possible to create an "uber" jar containing the project classes and the project dependencies as jars with a custom manifest file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832853/is-it-possible-to-create-an-uber-jar-containing-the-project-classes-and-the-pr/1834905#1834905)