# How to understand the relationship and use of spark --jars, extraClassPath and extraLibraryPath?

Tags: apache-spark, classpath

First of all, I have seen similar problems. [another problem link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit)  But I think its answer is not very clear.

Some of my questions are as follows：

（1）--jars parameter Is the same as the spark.executor.extraClassPath parameter, if they are different, what is the difference?

I have checked --help on the --jars in spark-submit command line, which explains as follows:

```
 Comma-separated list of local jars to include on the driver
                          and executor classpaths.
```

However, I did not find the explanation of spark.executor.extraClassPath in the spark-submit command line. finally, I found the following explanation about spark.executor.extraClassPath in the official website of spark:

```
Extra classpath entries to prepend to the classpath of executors.
```

Seemingly the same effect from the interpretation of the two ？

But I see the following paragraph from another question link:

> --jars vs SparkContext.addJar: These are identical, only one is set through spark submit and one via code. Choose the one which suites you better. One important thing to note is that using either of these options does not add the JAR to your driver/executor classpath, you'll need to explicitly add them using the extraClassPath config on both.

Why is this again?

（2）spark.executor.extraClassPath and spark.executor.extraLibraryPath, same as spark.driver.extraXXXXpath with the same prefix。

What is the difference between extraClassPath and extraLibraryPath?

Explanation of spark.executor.extraLibraryPath from spark official website。

```
Set a special library path to use when launching executor JVM's.
```

I don't understand, what is the difference between this explanation and --jars and spark.executor.extraClassPath?

I look forward to your explanation and answer，thank you .

Comment: Did you find a proper explanation?