# Connect GCP with PySpark without using Dataproc

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery

I'm trying to connect GCP (Google Big Query) with Spark (using pyspark) without using Dataproc (self-hosted Spark in the house), as listed on google official documentation it's only for Dataproc https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example? Any suggest? Note: My Spark & Hadoop setup on Docker. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [project page on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector) - it details how to reference the GCP credentials from the code.

In short, you should run

```py
spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile", "</path/to/key/file>").option("table", "<table>").load()
```

Please refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) on how to create the json credentials file if needed.

Comment: The spark. is SparkSession, SparkContext or SQLContext?

Comment: SparkSession. The convention for SparkContext is sc

Comment: Can I have a full sample code for how to begin and call for data, please? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/master/examples/python/shakespeare.py

Answer (score 0):

The BigQuery connector is available in a jar file as [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector#downloading-the-connector), it is publicly available. Then you can:

- Add it to the classpath on your on-premise/self-hosted cluster, so your applications can reach the BigQuery API.
- Add the connector only to your Spark applications, for example with the `--jars` option. Regarding this, there are some other possibilities that can impact your app, to know more please check [Add jars to a Spark Job - spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit)

Once the jar is added to the classpath you can check the [two bigquery connector examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector/tree/master/examples/python), one of them was already provided by @ David Rabinowitz