# How to connect pyspark (in local mode) to bigquery?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery

I am running pyspark in local mode, and I need to connect to bigquery. I have found this: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example but they focus on dataproc, and my spark is set up on a local machine.

Could someone please help me understand at a high level, in points, what exactly are the things I need to set up the connection and query the data into dataframes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki.

As per this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647067/connect-gcp-with-pyspark-without-using-dataproc?rq=2), you can connect pysparkto bigquery without using dataproc by running :

```
spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile", "</path/to/key/file>").option("table", "<table>").load()
```

Comment: what about the connectors? From which website would you download the jar? Could you share a specific link?