# spark-submit classNotFoundException : Unable to read from s3 in EMR

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

I'm stuck at trying to run a Spark application written in Scala on a spark cluster using the `spark-submit` command. The cluster is on EMR. It's more about the way spark send jars to the driver/executors and how it modifies the classpath.

My Application is not a fat Uber JAR, instead I have all the jars in a folder and I send them over the cluster at starting using `--jars` option.

Spark version is 2.4.4

This is how I run my application :

```
JARS=$(ls -m target/pack/lib/* | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\n')
# Note : I tried with/without including $HADOOP_JARS
HADOOP_JARS=$(ls -md /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*.jar | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\n')

spark-submit --master yarn \
  --class my.main.class \
  --driver-memory 2G\
  --executor-memory 3G\
  --executor-cores 2\
  --num-executors 2 \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dorg.bytedeco.javacpp.maxbytes=4G"\
  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dorg.bytedeco.javacpp.maxbytes=3G"\
  --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4G\
  --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=2048\
  --jars $JARS,$HADOOP_JARS \
  target/scala-2.11/tep_dl4j_2.11-1.0.jar arg1 arg2
```

Then I try to create a DataFrame by reading a CSV from S3. This is where problems begin :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jets3t/service/ServiceException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.createDefaultStore(NativeS3FileSystem.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.initialize(NativeS3FileSystem.java:333)
```

(I skip you all the stack trace)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jets3t.service.ServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 28 more
```

This class (org.jets3t.service.ServiceException) comes from `jets3t-0.9.0.jar` file which gets sent when starting cluster, according to this line :

```
INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar -> hdfs://ip-172-31-10-119.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1582370799483_0001/jets3t-0.9.0.jar
```

Even when I go to the Spark UI, I see the jar in Classpath Entries with the mention "Added by User". But still this exception.

I've looked around in SO and ended at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37348234/8054004). The only way to resolve it was to use the --driver-class-path option. Moreover, it says that `--jars` option "does not add the JAR to your driver/executor classpath". He is apparently right, but this is not what the documentation says. Indeed, according to the docs :

> When using spark-submit, the application jar along with any jars included with the --jars option will be automatically transferred to the cluster. URLs supplied after --jars must be separated by commas. That list is included in the driver and executor classpaths. Directory expansion does not work with --jars.

Am I missing something here ? What is the purpose of just sending jars over HDFS, but not include them in the classpath ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: EMR has jets3t installed (i just checked on a cluster); the way you deploy application (including the hadoop jars) is problematic, can you use the assembly plugin (sbt) or shaded (maven)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Including hadoop jars was only in my last attempt, to be sure that jets3t was actually shipped. Removing $HADOOP_JARS is not solving the issue.
Another point : When I don't use s3 for save/load data, everything works just fine, and my application load classes from external jars. 
 I know that I could make a Uber jar using assembly plugin, but I would like to understand why this fails in this particular case.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use client or cluster mode?

Comment: I have personally used `--jars` with `spark-shell` and they were definitely added to the classpath.

Comment: can you make an `echo $JARS` and echo `$HADOOP_JARS`? can you also share your mvn/sbt dependencies?

Comment: @Jasper-M Curiously I've just tried and indeed it works when I'm in cluster mode. I using client mode since the beginning. In cluster mode, spark driver has the same classpath as executor, and it seems that there are more jars added. I have written a small function that prints the classpath on the driver, and on executors. [Here](https://gist.github.com/ChrisYohann/d48aa1e68bd7cc6545791eaeeddbd8c4) is the result if it can help.

Comment: @SQL.injection
[build.sbt](https://gist.github.com/ChrisYohann/f2c1689dc5d4999b77c577ed65728017)
I use the sbt pack plugin which outputs all the dependencies in the `target/pack/lib` folder. I've used `sbt assembly` but I have the same problem too.
[plugins.sbt](https://gist.github.com/ChrisYohann/a357d37586bd38526cb848cd02579b1b)
Here is the output of the `echo $JARS` command  : [here](https://gist.github.com/ChrisYohann/4a891120057a06727ee6d38106b45e6d)
I also tried a minimal snippet :
[S3ReaderMain.scala](https://gist.github.com/ChrisYohann/8b201712c246eaa1b1f1d9d599195503)

Comment: Ok strange. If anything I would have expected the reverse.

Comment: I was getting the same error. I don't know the reason but removing `hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")` from my code made it work.