i cant read the avro file, however i have added correct jars but still the issue persists
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/Schema$Parser
error cased even after adding the correct jar and all import to read a avro file.. also using the correct spark submit as well (spark.read.format("avro").load("file:///F:/Data/projectsample.avro"))
can someone please resolve this issue.
I tried everything by adding the relevent jars as per spark version but no progress

This question is similar to: Add JAR files to a Spark job - spark-submit. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The error indicates that the jars you've added have not been picked up. As you've noted, this is a Spark issue.
Did you follow a solution as provided here?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37348234/3169109
Kind regards,
Oscar

If you are sure that link answers the question, you should flag as a duplicate instead of answering so it gets linked appropriately.

As the OP hasn't detailed how (s)he tried, I wasn't certain. With a few days without reply, the change of this being a duplicate becomes large enough to flag it.
